# how to get a custom attribute in a user pool using aws-android-sdk

Tags: amazon-cognito

I can connect to aws user pool using aws-android-sdk. I can get standard attributes such as e-mail, given name etc... but IMPOSSIBLE to get a custom attribute.
Here is the function used:

```
GetDetailsHandler detailsHandler = new GetDetailsHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserDetails cognitoUserDetails) {
            // Extract user details
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Sergey Kovalev

`cognitoUserDetails` has `CognitoUserAttributes` and `CognitoUserSettings`

```
cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes(); // returns UserAttributes 
cognitoUserDetails.getSettings(); //returns UserSettings
```

You have to call getAttributes() once again to get the Hash Mapped attributes values.

To retrieve `custom:preferred_name` use the following code.

```
Map mDetails = cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes();
String name = mDetails.get("custom:preferred_name").toString();
```

Check the AWS User Pools Console > Pool Details to get clarity on the attribute names.

```
Required attributes name, phone_number
Alias attributes preferred_username
Custom attributes custom:company, custom:location
```

I have used this in Android.

Comment: this only works if the user is logged in, correct? What about if there is no session, how to get attributes?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder You are right this is details from the user who has logged in. But don't know how to get all users data. One way might be to use AWS Cognito Groups. 
Not using Cognito for a long time will check it.

Answer (score 2):

You must mark the custom attribute as readable. See below:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248330

Comment: Please include more detail how that might be achieved.

Comment: You do this under User Pools > App Clients in the AWS Web Console. Then go to "Set attribute read and write permissions". You should see a list of attributes to toggle R/W. Once I toggled mine to R it came through

Comment: Link is dead.  Really dead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getAttributes()` of `CognitoUserAttributes` class to get user attributes.

Take a look at documentation
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognitoidentityprovider/CognitoUserAttributes.html

and source code

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognitoidentityprovider/CognitoUserAttributes.java

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was doing exactly what you suggested. When I get the cognitoUserDetails, I call the getAttributes(). The problem is I can get all standard attributes like nickname, address, birthdate etc... But any custom attribute is no return in the getAttributes()!

Comment: For your information I can get custom attribute using the aws cli. with the command: aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id xxxxxxxx --username xxxxxxxx. But it is impossible with aws-android-sdk to get custom attributes info using cognitoUserDetails getAttributes().

Answer (score 0):

Basically, with Cognito on an authenticated user (CognitoUser object) you can call the methods for retrieving (getUserAttributes) and updating attributes (updateAttributes). Note that if you defined a custom attribute such as preferred_name for example, you need to reference such as below when using it:

```
custom:preferred_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles reading/writing custom attributes until i deleted the user pool and created the attributes when creating a new pool (rather than doing it after as I did for the original pool).